# Windows Phone Webbrowser - Cannot input text on empty line in contenteditable div

Tags: c#, html, windows-phone

I'm developing a note app in Windows Phone 8.1 and here is a bug I cannot fix.

Say you have an WebBrowser control and loaded a html page, inside which is a content-editable div.

```
<div id="content" contenteditable="true">
    <div>Please edit content here...</div>
</div>
```

After running this app, I can edit content inside div.

The strange thing is, If I tap return several times,  there will be several empty lines. Then I tap empty line before current caret position, and try to input text there. It turns out I cannot input text there, and text will always append to last line of the entire div.

```
content here...



(Wish to insert text here.)



But text goes here.
```

I tested it on my lumia 925 device running Windows Phone 8.1 and using Chinse Input Method.